# Syntax error in ply(lex/yacc) when input text file is not in sequence with the grammar sequence

Tags: python, syntax-error, yacc, context-free-grammar, ply

The following code works well when the text file are in sequence with code i.e, **Introduction** then **Information** but gives error if **Information** comes before **Introduction**. What would be the solution to handle this using lex/yacc? Thank in advance.

```
import ply.lex as lex

# List of token names.   This is always required
tokens = [
    'CheckupInformation',
    'Introduction',
    'Information',
    'perfect',
    'sick',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'CHAR',
    'NUMBER'
    ] 
def t_CheckupInformation(t)     : 'CheckupInformation'     ; return t
def t_Introduction(t)  : 'Introduction'  ; return t
def t_Information(t) : 'Information' ; return t
def t_perfect(t): 'perfect'; return t
def t_sick(t) : 'sick'; return t



t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
t_CHAR = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*'
t_ignore = " \t"
# Define a rule so we can track line numbers

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'[+\-0-9_][0-9_]*'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        print("Integer value too large %s" % t.value)
        t.value = 0
    return t
def t_SEMICOLON(t):
    r'\;.*'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
# Error handling rule
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

 # Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()
# define upper level classes first     
class stat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statement = ""
        self.intro = list()
        self.body = list()


P=stat()
def p_stat(p):
    'Stat : LPAREN CheckupInformation statIntro statBody RPAREN'
    p[0]=(p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5])

def p_Intro(p) : 
    '''statIntro : LPAREN Introduction Name RPAREN
                 | statIntro LPAREN Introduction Name RPAREN
                 | empty'''

    if len(p)==5:
       p[0] = (p[3])
    elif len(p)==6:
       p[0] = (p[4])
    else:
       p[0]= None
    P.intro.append(p[0])

def p_Name(p):
    'Name : CHAR'
    p[0]=p[1]



def p_Body(p):
    '''statBody : LPAREN Information bodyinfo RPAREN
                | statBody LPAREN Information bodyinfo RPAREN'''
    if len(p)==5:
       p[0] = (p[3])
    elif len(p)==6:
       p[0] = (p[4])
    P.body.append(p[0])
def p_bodyinfo(p):
    '''bodyinfo : LPAREN CHAR perfect RPAREN
                | LPAREN CHAR sick RPAREN'''
    p[0]=p[2],p[3]


def p_empty(p):
    'empty :  '
    print("This function is called")
    pass   
def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error in input '%s'!" % p.value)

import ply.yacc as yacc
parser = yacc.yacc()
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
    sys.exit("Usage: %s <filename>" % sys.argv[0])
fp = open(sys.argv[1])
contents=fp.read()
result=parser.parse(contents)

print("(CheckupInformation")
if (P.intro) != None:
    for x in range(len(P.intro)):
        print("    (Introduction %s)" %(P.intro[x]))
for x in range(len(P.body)):
        print("    (Information( %s %s))" %(P.body[x]))
print(")")
```

The code works well for file1 & cannot handle file2.

**ERROR:**
**Syntax error in input '(Introduction'!**
**(CheckupInformation
    (Introduction None)
    (Information( Anonymous1 perfect))
)**

**File1:**

```
(CheckupInformation
  (Introduction John)
  (Introduction Patt)
  (Information(Anonymous1 perfect))
  (Information(Anonymous2 sick))
)
```

**File2:**

```
(CheckupInformation

  (Information(Anonymous1 perfect))
  (Information(Anonymous2 sick))
  (Introduction John)
  (Introduction Patt)
)
```

Comment: I think the answer is in the postscript to [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61966032/1566221), where I said "First, you might decide that it doesn't really matter what order B, C and D are presented in the above production. In that case, you could replace `A : optional_B optional_C optional_D` with the not-too-complicated, somewhat more accepting alternative:..." (You'll have to check the other answer to see the alternative, because it doesn't quite fit in a comment.)

Comment: @rici thank you for your comment but I am not getting the answer. Now in my example the order/sequence matters, please suggest how to solve that. ( There could be 44 optional item)

Comment: Your question here is: "how do I handle this if the order of Introduction and Information doesn't matter." But now you're saying the order does matter. Could you clarify? What orders matter and what orders do not matter?

Comment: Although I don't think I said it with respect to your other question either, my view is that parsers should either handle a fixed sequence of precisely ordered non-optional components or an arbitrary order of optional components. If your needs are more complex than those two, chose the second one and use the action function to verify that you got the right combination of components. It's not only parsers which have trouble handling precisely ordered sequences of 44 optional things; people get the order wrong, too.

Comment: @rici sorry for the confusion in my question. Actually I meant that in the input text file the components can be ordered differently & also the components can be optional. Now I want to handle those with my code.

Comment: Right, and that part of my answer is about recognizing optional components in any order. Maybe you can give me a hint about why it doesn't meet your needs. What information does it lack?

Comment: @rici Thank you for your response. May be I am not getting how to make changes accordingly in my code. Can you please help again by showing changes in my code? That would be a great help indeed.

Comment: Moreover, if any components is missing now the code can handle according to your previous solution to my previous question. But it cannot handle if the text file components are not in order.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you wanted, but I found myself unable to just change one or two lines in your code. The following is still far from perfect, but I think it is approaching a reasonable approach to your problem. I tried to annotate it with useful comments. Please read through it carefully and try to understand why I did what I did, referring to the Ply manual as necessary (some references are in the code comments, but there's lots of useful background information in the document which I didn't reference specifically).

Good luck.

```py
import ply.lex as lex

# Keyword handling copied from the Ply manual, https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6
reserved = {
    'CheckupInformation': 'TK_CheckupInformation',
    'Introduction': 'TK_Introduction',
    'Information': 'TK_Information',
    'perfect': 'TK_perfect',
    'sick': 'TK_sick',
}

# I changed CHAR to WORD because CHAR sounds like a character
tokens = ['NUMBER','WORD'] + list(reserved.values())

def t_WORD(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'WORD')    # Check for reserved words
    return t

# See the Ply manual: https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn11
literals = '()'

# See the Ply manual: https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn8
t_ignore = ' \t\n'
t_ignore_COMMENT = r'\;.*'

# Fixed the regex. You can't have a sign in the middle of a number.
def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'[+-]?[0-9_]+'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        print("Integer value too large %s" % t.value)
        t.value = 0
    return t

# See below for the definition of lineno_for_token
# Error handling rule
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s' at line %d'" % (
        t.value[0], t.lexer.lineno_for_token(t)))
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

# Ply tracks the character index automatically as lexer.lexpos, and every
# token it produces has a lexpos attribute. So there is no need to misuse
# the lineno attribute for that purpose. It should be the line number of
# the token, as its name indicates.
# You don't seem to use lineno (or lexpos) anywhere, but it is handy for
# error messages. But since it is used rarely, it's easier to compute it
# on demand by counting newlines to the lex position.
# Perhaps this should just be added to the lexer we just built.
lex.Lexer.lineno_for_token = lambda self, t: 1 + self.lexdata.count('\n', 0, t.lexpos)

# Fixed this to use an upper-class name and to derive from object.
# Object to hold a top-level description
class Stat(object):
    # Attributes used for components
    components = {'intro', 'body'}

    def __init__(self, component_dict):
        self.statement = ""  # I don't know what this is used for
        # Copy the components dictionary as attributes, using
        # an empty list as default
        for k in self.components:
            setattr(self, k, component_dict.get(k, ()))
        # Verify that we used every key in the dict.
        for k in component_dict.keys():
            if k not in self.components:
                print("Warning! Ignoring " + k
                      + " because it is not in Stat.components")

    # Arrange for the object to print as expected
    def __repr__(self):
        return '(CheckupInformation %r %r)' % (self.intro, self.body)

# Instead of having a global "P" object (whose name is not very useful),
# we return a Stat object
def p_stat(p):
    """ stat : '(' TK_CheckupInformation components ')' """
    p[0] = Stat(p[3])

# We allow all components to be optional and order independent here. We
# also allow them all to be repeated. But that could be made more precise.

# components is a dictionary whose values are lists
def p_components_empty(p):
    """ components : """
    p[0] = { }

def p_components_append(p):
    """ components : components component """
    p[0] = p[1]
    # The component is a two-element tuple
    key, value = p[2]
    if key in p[0]:
        p[0][key].append(value)
    else:
        p[0][key] = [value]

# Syntax for each component type (just one element, not a list)
# component is a tuple of (key, value)
# All of the productions just copy the value from some specific syntax.
def p_component(p):
    """ component : statIntro
                  | statBody
    """
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_statIntro(p): 
    """statIntro : '(' TK_Introduction WORD ')' """
    p[0] = ('intro', p[3])

def p_statBody(p):
    """statBody : '(' TK_Information bodyinfo ')' """
    p[0] = ('body', p[3])

# bodyinfo is a tuple of (identifier, status)
def p_bodyinfo(p):
    """bodyinfo : '(' WORD TK_perfect ')'
                | '(' WORD TK_sick ')'
    """
    p[0] = (p[2],p[3])

def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error in input '%s'! at line %d" % (
        p.value, p.lexer.lineno_for_token(p)))

import ply.yacc as yacc

parser = yacc.yacc()

# Only do this if we're called from the command line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
        sys.exit("Usage: %s <filename>" % sys.argv[0])

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
        stat = parser.parse(fp.read())

    if stat is not None:
        print("(CheckupInformation")
        for x in range(len(stat.intro)):
            print("    (Introduction %s)" %(stat.intro[x]))
        for x in range(len(stat.body)):
            print("    (Information( %s %s))" %(stat.body[x]))
        print(")")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your valuable time. But this solution almost changes everything of my code. I am looking for some code with less changes.

Comment: @learner: yes, your code needs quite a few fixes, I'm afraid. But you can try focussing on the changes to the grammar, which show the basic idea in a way which is perhaps more concrete than the narrative in my other answer.

Comment: @Learner: One stylistic point: your code (like much of the Ply code I see on the web) frequently combines two different productions in the same action function and then needs to use an explicit test to see which production triggered the action. It's a lot better to separate those into two different functions. Combining the two productions into a single function throws away information that the parser already figured out (which production it was) and then wastes time figuring it out again. See, for example, the two functions dealing with `components` in my sample code.